# How to store the computed MFCC features for a multiple pronunciation of single word?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

I am trying to implement the digit recognition system in Hindi. I have recorded multiple pronunciations for a single digit. So, inorder to train the system how can I store the mfcc features extracted for multiple pronunciation for each digit, Should it be in one fiele or multiple files?

Comment: Depends on what you will use for training. Usually it's multiple files or some structure in memory if your training system takes data from memory.

Comment: So While using HMM inorder to train each digit I have to give multiple files as input (multiple utterance feature) to that digit HMM or will be different HMM for Different pronunciation. Or simply tell me how to create HMM for multiple pronunciation of single digit.

Comment: You train a single HMM for multiple samples of a digit. Details depend on the framework you are using. Is it Matlab HMM toolbox or Numpy HMM or Jahmm or something else.

Comment: Matlab HMM toolbox HTK

Comment: In HTK you need to store audio samples separately and generate separate MFC samples. Then you can pass them to HInit. You can check tutorial for details http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial

Comment: Sir, Till now i have gone through all the basics of HMM, how can i train HMM for single word and how should I create a linguistic and acoustic model ?